# Php return function

Tags: php, wordpress

So I got this :

```
<?php
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_register', 10, 2);

function add_register($items) {
$register = wp_register(false);
$items .= '<div class="foo">' . $register .'</div>';
return $items;


}
```

Why this is not returning  . $register .

Comment: Are you gonna ask a question? This is just a statement.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is why this is not returning <div class="foo">' . $register .'</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
 wp_register('', '',false);
```

[wp_register( $before, $after, $echo);](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register)

Answer (score 1):

This is shorter:

```
function add_register($items) {
    return $items . wp_register('<div class="foo">', '</div>', false);
}
```